# Android: Cannot open downloaded file from notification. Error: "Can't open file"

Tags: android, android-volley, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

My app downloads a file from the internet and saves it into "Downloads" folder as well as providing a notification, that file has been downloaded. When I click the notification, I have created chooserIntent to select an app to open the file. However, any app I choose won't open the file with error message: "Can't open file", but when I go to a file manager it opens fine. I guess it is something related to permissions?
BTW, Uri is obtained like this (Android 7.1):

```
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivityContext(), getAppContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
```

Here is my code for notification:

```
private Notification downloadCompleteNotification(String title, String message, Uri uri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getString(R.string.open_file_with));
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = initBasicBuilder(title, message, intent);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_u));
    builder.setOngoing(false);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, chooser, 0);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    return builder.build();
}

private NotificationCompat.Builder initBasicBuilder(String title, String text, Intent intent) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.u)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text);
    if (intent != null) {
        TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        taskStackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);
    }
    return builder;
}
```

Comment: Your android version?

Comment: As I said: android 7.1.

Comment: Oh i missed it.. Have you given READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  runtime  permission?

Comment: I have defined it in Manifest file, but I do not in runtime. I ll look into that now.

Comment: No.. You should be doing runtime permission for latest version.. Try it.. here is link which can help you : https://www.sitepoint.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-m-and-n/

Comment: I have a same problem. I think the permissions are not matter here. In my case I want to open downloaded file after `DownloadManager` finished downloading the file. The strange thing in my case is if I wait a few seconds and then open the file, every thing is OK, but if I open the file immediately, same error happens. The problem in my case occurs only on android 7 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your onCreate method activity. You can add multiple permission here seperated by commas

```
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

        if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }
```

And add this function:

```
public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `API level 23` or above. You need to give `Run Time` permission. As well as inside manifest file.

```
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
     Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
     Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};


private boolean checkPermissions() {
        int result;
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String p : PERMISSIONS_STORAGE) {
            result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, p);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
            }
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission granted.
                } else {
                    //code for deny
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried requesting reading permissions, but it seems the app has those permissions. I checked through debugging. Again, let's make it clear external application cannot open downloaded file when asked from notification of my app, but can, in fact, open it from file manager.